# Google Spreadsheet IMPORTHTML importing Null

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, pageload

I have an html file that pulls data from an XML URL.

When I browse the html via browser, I can see it load the data in the table.

However it pulls `NULL` in the GoogleSpread.

For whatever reason the data from XML can't be pulled from Google Spreadsheet directly. I have to pull it from my webserver then pull that to Google Spreadsheet.

Here is the html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

 <body onload="loadXMLDoc()">

  <table>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td id="demo"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>

    <script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          myFunction(xmlhttp);
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function myFunction(xml) {
      var i;
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
      for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        table += "<tr><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td></tr>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the Google Spreadsheet formula:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://example.com/xml/myscript.html","table",1)
```

Comment: Copy/paste your code works for me...  Can you share your spreadsheet?

Comment: Your server is not accessible from internet?

Comment: yes it is...but for whatever reason the data from XML can't be pulled from Google Spreadsheet directly. I have to pull on my pc or on my webserver.

Comment: so you are dynamically generating (using javascript) html in your page and using `IMPORTHTML` in google sheet to import that dynamically generated html?

Comment: @th1rdey3 Yes.I dont have to use `IMPORTHTML` my goal is to pull that data from web to Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: i think you are getting null because you are setting the html using javascript. can you create a separate url(rest api) to use for importing?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because it is making an ajax call - for example the "sample" xml your showing is actually calling "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml" and so that is the url with the actual data on it.

You can pull in the data you want by using

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml","//CD")
```

Comment: How?  Have you even tried  my formula?  Your importhtml formula will never work and will always come back empty because the data is populated from the Ajax script and xml doesn't contain tables

Comment: and if I am missing the point - then please explain what you actually are trying to achieve

Comment: if I use IMPORTXML then it will use google's server ipaddress to pull. I need to pull it using my server.

Comment: you should really add those details to your original question - otherwise no one is going to know